# Trigger con errores de compilacion

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, trigger

Bueno resulta que quiero hacer un trigger que cuando actualice una columna en especifico se anexen los registros de la tabla es decir tengo una tabla articulos donde cuando realice la venta y se descuente la cantidad esa informacion valla a dar a una tabla ventas. acontinuacion mostrare el codigo:

```
create table articulos( 
id_articulo number(5) primary key,
nombre varchar2(32),
detalle varchar2(32),
precio number(8) not null,
cantidad number(10) not null,
);
create table ventas(
    id_venta number(5) primary key,
    id_articulo number(5) references articulos,
    id_empleado number(6) references empleado, 
    id_cliente  number(5) references cliente, 
    cantidad number(10) not null,
    precio number(8) not null,
    total number(8) not null,
    fecha_venta date
);
```

El disparador es el siguiente:

```
 create sequence id_venta
start with 1
increment by 1
order;

create or replace trigger anexventa
before update on articulos
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
declare
x number;
begin
select id_venta.nextval into x from dual;
 :new.id_venta := x;
if updating('cantidad') then
insert into  ventas values(:NEW.id_venta, :old.id_articulo, :old.id_empleado, :old.id_cliente, :NEW.cantidad, :NEW.precio, :NEW.total, sysdate);
end if;
end anexventa;
/
```

**Como ven anexe una secuencia la cual me permite generar el id de la venta automaticamente.**

Los errores que me arroja son:

```
SQL> show errors trigger anexventa;
Errors for TRIGGER ANEXVENTA:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/2      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID_VENTA'
7/28     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.ID_VENTA'
7/61     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID_EMPLEADO'
7/79     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID_CLIENTE'
7/124    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TOTAL'
```

Espero alguien pueda orientarme con respecto al problema saludos.

Comment: Si quieres acceder a otra tabla para modificarla puedes hacer una funcion a parte donde puedas actualizar la tabla articulos y llamarla desde tu triguer o hacer una funcion en la cual este dentro el trigger.

Comment: No es lo mismo: a) *"Actualizar las existencias debido a la venta"* que b) *"Crear una venta debido a la actualización de las existencias"*.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines un disparador para la tabla `articulos`:

```
before update on articulos
```

... entonces obviamente, solo tendrás acceso a las columnas de esa tabla con `:OLD.xxx` o `:NEW.xxx`.

En tu caso, estás tratando de acceder a columnas de la tabla `venta` en el disparador para la tabla `articulos`. Eso no tiene sentido. Limítate a usar las columnas de la tabla `articulos`.

Comment: Pero es que lo que busco es que yo al realizar una actualizacion en la tabla articulos en la columna cantidad  pueda  mandar esos resultados a la tabla ventas ¿Cómo haria eso?

Comment: No creo que puedes hacerlo con un trigger, porque no tienes disponible toda la información que necesitas. Vas a tener que usar un procedimiento, o algo así.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que el diseño de la bbdd me parece incorrecto para lo que quieres hacer, ya que el trigger debería estar en Ventas, no en Artículos ya que los datos que quieres insertar no se encuentran en esa tabla.

Por otra parte, atendiendo estrictamente a tu código:

1. `'NEW.ID_VENTA'` puedes usar directamente la variable que has creado "`x`" para la secuencia.
2. `'OLD.ID_EMPLEADO', 'OLD.ID_CLIENTE'` Son elementos que no tienes en la tabla Articulos, por tanto no vas a poder acceder a ellos directamente. Pero si lo que quieres es obtener estos datos de una venta anterior que se corresponda, puedes buscarla usando una Select intermedia filtrando por ID, nombre, o algún otro dato que tengas que incorporar a tu tabla Ventas para identificarla. Por tanto, antes de la línea de Insert en Ventas puedes hacer esto:

   SELECT ID_EMPLEADO, ID_CLIENTE into idEmp,idCli FROM Ventas WHERE ID_ARTICULO = :NEW.id_articulo
3. 'NEW.TOTAL' deberías poder calcularlo (precio x cantidad), y meter el resultado directamente en el Insert

pd: como consejo, está estandarizado usar los nombre de las tablas en singular.